# Do hooks in Mocha run regardless of test failures?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Just like the title says. Do `before`/`after`/`beforeEach`/`afterEach` hooks in Mocha work even if tests fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do run even if the test fail.
However, if you run Mocha with the bail option, the teardown hooks will not run.

Just did an quick check with existing test suites here.
The code:

```
setup(function() {
    console.log("1");
});
teardown(function() {
    console.log("2");
});
```

The executions:

```
D:\Dev\JS\toposort>mocha


  Toposort
    ◦ should sort correctly: 1
    √ should sort correctly
2
    ◦ should find cyclic dependencies: 1
    1) should find cyclic dependencies
2
    ◦ #2 - should add the item if an empty array of dependencies is passed: 1
    √ #2 - should add the item if an empty array of dependencies is passed
2


  2 passing (15 ms)
  1 failing

  1) Toposort should find cyclic dependencies:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to not throw 'Error' but [Error: Cyclic dependency found. '3' is dependent of itself
.] was thrown

D:\Dev\JS\toposort>mocha --bail


  Toposort
    ◦ should sort correctly: 1
    √ should sort correctly
2
    ◦ should find cyclic dependencies: 1
    1) should find cyclic dependencies


  1 passing (14 ms)
  1 failing

  1) Toposort should find cyclic dependencies:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to not throw 'Error' but [Error: Cyclic dependency found. '3' is dependent of itself
.] was thrown
```

Comment: Okay. How are setup() and teardown() related to before[Each]() and after[Each]() related? Are before/after just aliases for setup/teardown?

Comment: In this case, I'm using the TDD interface. The before/after and variations are specific from the BDD interface, and they work the same way. [See here](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#interfaces) for more info

Comment: But after does not run if one of the before's fail which is pretty annoying. If my register succeeds and my authenticate fails it doesn't clean out my test user.